# Full text search form with multiple inputs

Tags: mongodb, search, full-text-search, mongodb-query

I try to create search form that has three text inputs:

- item description;
- model name;
- ctg name.

User can fill all those inputs and search through collection that has next document structure:

```
{
"id" : 123,
"description" : "Ricoh Aficio CL-4000 Type 245 Toner Yellow",
"pnbrs" : [ 
    "888281", 
    "K174/G", 
    "K174G"
],
"model" : [ 
    {
        "id" : "1625",
        "name" : "Ricoh Aficio CL4000DN"
    }, 
],
"ctg" : [ 
    {
        "id" : "1472",
        "name" : "Ricoh Type 245 Toner"
    }
],
"brand" : "Ricoh"
```

}

Also I created text index:

```
    db.products.ensureIndex({ 
        description: "text",
        "model.name" : "text", 
        "ctg.name" : "text"
    });
```

How to organize relevant full text search by those three text inputs and have on the top items with maximum score?

For example, user want to search by "model.name":"XXX", how to leave in search result only items that has "XXX" string in "model.name" and exclude those that have "XXX" in "description" or "ctg.name" fields?

Comment: Simply create a text index over the fields you want to search. It's all in the docs.

Comment: You're coming off a little vague here. It's really all about the "terms" you use in your search. But presumably you are talking about "weighting" the response so that matches in certain fields rank higher? Is this what you are really asking? If not then please edit to make it more clear what you expect.

Comment: I already created Index over the fields. For example, user want to search by "model.name":"XXX". How to leave in search result only items that has "XXX" string in "model.name" and exclude those that have "XXX" in "description" or "ctg.name" fields?